# Recipe calls for a heaping teaspoon of a liquid ingredient

Tags: oil, measurements

I'm looking at [a recipe for chickpeas (garbanzo beans) roasted in a spice mix](http://www.simple-veganista.com/2013/09/sriracha-curry-roasted-chickpeas.html), which looks yummy, but I'm confused by some items in the ingredients list.

I'm happy with this:

> 1 heaping teaspoon curry powder

I simply take my 5ml measuring spoon, and get a heaped scoop of curry powder.

But for

> 1 heaping teaspoon sesame, coconut or olive oil
>
> 1 heaping teaspoon sriracha

I can see that sriracha might well hold its shape enough to form a heap. But what about the oil??

Comment: Not every teaspoon used in kitchens has the same size anyway.

Comment: @mkrieger1 A teaspoon is a standard measure unit that [approximates to 4,92892 ml](https://www.google.es/search?q=4.92892159+milliliters&oq=teaspoon&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j6j0l4.2903j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=teaspoon+to+ml)

Comment: technically, coconut oil could be heaping, depending on the temperature.

Comment: I think that means some is dibbling over (and into your dish) before you turn the measuring spoon over and empty it measured amount.  But, yeah, not the best use of language there.

Comment: While the answers provided are certainly reasonable I would offer another likely issue...the writer had a 'brain f*rt' (It happens to people all the time, this is not a insult or judgement)

Comment: @CosCallis or a bad translation - in UK English at least it is a heaped teaspoon not heaping

Comment: @Mark I believe that in American, 'heaping' is the standard adjective

Comment: You can sorta heap a spoon of liquid if you use a spoon with sufficiently vertical sides, surface tension allows you to slightly overfill it. Though i'm by no means sure if thats what they mean.

Comment: You can post comments on that recipe site and the author of the recipe seems to be actively responding to queries. Why don't you just ask her to clarify the quantities?

Comment: Maybe the writer refrigerates their oils at a low enough temperature to make the solid fats, which can be heaped.

Comment: Probably a case of a heaping over-use of copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a typo - the poster has corrected it, by deleting the 'heaping' on the oil.  But, mysteriously, left it on the sriracha.  Maybe her sriracha comes in powdered form...    I don't think it's a second-language issue, her English looks native to me.

Comment: Sriracha is a bit thicker than other liquids. Otherwise, sounds like a _viscous_ cycle.

Comment: After so much interest and useful comment, turns out to have been a typo. I see [cooking.se] doesn't have a 'too localized' close reason, so let's call it a day here...

Answer (score 33):

Obviously you can't "heap" a liquid.

What helps is if you remember that in cooking measurements are not set in stone. The amount given in a recipe can basically always be tweaked to your liking - a tablespoon need not be the "perfect" amount, but should be a good starting point. E.g. the siracha: some like their dish hotter, some less so.

In your case I'd interpret "heaping" as "generous" or "a bit more than". (The opposite of "scant", where you'd fill the spoon not quite full.)

I'd start with a spoonful and add more to taste, if necessary.

Comment: Technically it is possible to "heap" liquids thanks to [surface tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension), to a certain degree at least. (I like the answer, just thought of mentioning this bit of trivia.)

Comment: @undercat please make that an answer, because IMHO that's what the recipe means. The more viscous a liquid, the more it can be heaped.

Answer (score 10):

The recipe looks like it was written by someone who doesn't speak English as their first language. A heaping spoon of a liquid is nonsensical. My best guess is to use about half-again the spoon measurement, so 7-8ml.

Comment: Why is that your best guess? If it's a non-english speaker, they most likely meant just a normal teaspoon

Comment: @theonlygusti That's why it's a guess! Personally, I would assume the use of 'heaping' means 'somewhat more than', but like I said, it's just a guess.

Comment: @theonlygusti I find it much more likely that a non-native speaker would think "a heaping teaspoon means 'a bit more than a teaspoon'" and not realize the nuance that you can't heap a liquid, than that they'd think "a heaping teaspoon is just a teaspoon."

Comment: @DavidRicherby 'heaping teaspoon' is a bit idiomatic.  If it was literal, it would be a 'heaped' teaspoon.  We aren't using the teaspoon to heap things.  A 'heaping helping of whoop-ass' is not actually a bunch of whoop-ass arranged in heap. It seems quite likely that if someone might not know what 'heaping' means and just know that's what you call an teaspoon filled above the top.

Comment: @JimmyJames That's exactly what I said: they'd think a heaping teaspoon means a bit more than a teaspoon, not that it's just a strange way of saying "a teaspoon".

Comment: @DavidRicherby It seems I parsed your sentence incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

From looking at the recipe, and from my experience with roasted chickpeas, I think it would be fine with or without "heaping". If I think of heaping oil, I would just fill the spoon until it's just about to overflow, or even overflows a bit. I honestly don't think it would make a huge difference either way with this recipe.